# Удаление из таблицы записей содержащихся в другой таблице

Tags: sql, sqlite

Даны например две таблицы. Первая "продукты":

```
|номер партии|номер компании|название|цена|
```

и вторая "просроченные":

```
|номер партии|номер компании|
```

как мне удалить записи из таблицы "продукты" определяя их по номеру партии и номеру компании из таблицы "просроченные" более логичным и быстродействующим путем. Или лучше использовать цикл в самой программе и удалять по очереди забирая значения из таблицы "просроченные" и проверяя их наличие в таблице продукты?

Comment: А связь между таблицами какая? есть уникальные идентификаторы?

Comment: `delete from table1 where id in(select id from table2)` - я бы попробовал как то так, как вариант построить индекс по полям Номер партии и Номер компании

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from [Продукты]
  where [номер_партии] in (select [номер_партии] from [просроченные])
    and [номер_компании] in (select [номер_компании] from [просроченные])
```

Пробуйте. Но условие не достаточное. Нет уникальности записей.

Comment: Два вложенных запроса в условии, мне как кажется, как-то расточительно. Вроде так лучше `DELETE FROM [Продукты] WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [просроченные] WHERE [просроченные].[номер_партии] = [Продукты].[номер_партии] AND [просроченные].[номер_компании] = [Продукты].[номер_компании])`

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin это уберётся, при наличии ключей. Вы можете предложить другой вариант?

Comment: через EXISTS. Сразу хотел предложить, но нечаянно отправил, а затем пока редактировал, вы уже успели задать вопрос. )

Comment: Всего в списке просроченных 11694 строки. Выполнение запроса от Vasil'а занимает 38 секунд и удаляет все верно(11694 строки из списка продуктов) а запрос Atlantis'a и Bald'а занимает почти 3 секунды но почему-то удаляет 11710 строк. Хотелось бы добиться точности при меньшем времени ожидания. Ведь таблица просроченных будет расти и расти.

Comment: @АмирАфендин про Bulk delete что-нибудь слышали?

Comment: Сейчас пробежался в интернете глазами. Не думаю что он уместен в моей ситуации. У меня программа на Qt.

Comment: "Нет уникальности записей" если это поможет поподробнее об этом можно?Насколько я знаю нельзя 2 поля объединить в один primary key.

Comment: @АмирАфендин можно объединить два поля в primary key. Это называется составной ключ. Но лучше добавить в таблицу id autoincrement и связывать таблицы по нему. Поиск по id работает в несколько раз быстрее чем по текстовому полю. Или номер партии у вас числовое значение?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте через **`delete from`**. Например, в Oracle это можно сделать как:

```
delete from {Продукты}
where {номер партии} in (select {номер партии} from {Просроченные})
      and {номер компании} in (select {номер компании} from {Просроченные})
```

В результате, у вас из таблицы **`Продукты`** удалятся те строки, которые присутствуют по `номеру партии` и `номеру компании` в таблице **`Просроченные`**, и не нужен никакой цикл в программе в итоге.

Comment: Ваш, ответ, собственно, ни чем не отличается от моего.

Comment: @Atlantis собственно, разница в минуту - пока писал, вы опубликовали на несколько десятков секунд раньше.